# Flutter Call Listener from another class

Tags: flutter, textfield, textformfield

I am pretty new to Flutter (coming from Java) and making my way through the first Android application.

In my project, I am using a different class to create a reusable widget (from the example [here](https://itnext.io/reusable-widgets-reusable-custom-appbars-in-flutter-4d4b8b06d176)), that works perfectly with all methods, but I can't figure out a way to define and reuse the method `onEditingComplete`.

Here is my code:

```
class AppTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  AppTextField({
    this.controller,
    this.textInputType,
    this.pwValidator,

    this.editingComplete,  // this the method that is causing the problem
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  final FormFieldValidator pwValidator;

  final Listener editingComplete;  //  This doesn't work. Am I using the wrong listener?

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primaryColorDark: Colors.blue,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 15, 25, 0),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            keyboardType: null == textInputType ? textInputType : textInputType,
            validator: null == pwValidator ? pwValidator : pwValidator,

            // I am facing problems with this line of code 
            onEditingComplete:  null == editingComplete ? editingComplete : editingComplete,                
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class where I want to implement and reuse the widget :

```
Container(
    child: AppTextField(

          controller: _controllerPassword,              
          pwValidator: (value) { },
          
          onEditingComplete:          // here is where I am facing difficulties              
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property [onEditingComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onEditingComplete.html) is a [VoidCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html). Which is a function without parameter and does not return any data.

In `AppTextField` define `onEditingComplete` as

```
final VoidCallback onEditingComplete;
```

Then assign it to the `onEditingComplete` property of the TextFormField. Also, get rid of the ternary operators.

```
onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete
```

And when using the widget, pass the callback like so:

```
Container(
  child: AppTextField(

      controller: _controllerPassword,              
      pwValidator: (value) { },
      
      onEditingComplete:   (){
          //Do what you want to do here.
      }           
),
```

Comment: Cool man, very much appreciated. I figured it had something do with the callback. Thanks for the explanation and the code snippet... and thanks for the suggestion to get rid of the ternary operators. The code works smooth and looks nice and clean.